# Cpanel uapi email verify_password by php

Tags: php, cpanel

Anyone here manage to use `Cpanel SDK uapi:email:verify_password` by `php`?

I can't find any source how to use it or implement.
Please give some guide by simple example.

Comment: Use Curl to communicate with  the API endpoints , I never worked with Cpanel APIs, When looking into the API it has clear documentation., https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Averify_password

Comment: Dear Reiah Paul Sam,
Can you teach me by giving some sample how to do it?
Sebastian Ng

Comment: Have you got any SDK for Development, and any Class named `cpanel.php` is there ?